# Is there a way to make AngularJS load partials in the beginning and not at when needed?

Tags: angularjs

I have a route setup like this:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/landing', {
            templateUrl: '/landing-partial',
            controller: landingController
        }).
        when('/:wkspId/query', {
            templateUrl: '/query-partial',
            controller: queryController
        }).
        otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/landing'
        });
}]);
```

I want to be able to make angularjs download both the partials in the beginning and not when requested.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 270, accepted):

Yes, there are at least 2 solutions for this:

1. Use the `script` directive ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3ascript)) to put your partials in the initially loaded HTML
2. You could also fill in `$templateCache` ([http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$templateCache](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache)) from JavaScript if needed (possibly based on result of `$http` call)

If you would like to use method (2) to fill in `$templateCache` you can do it like this:

```
$templateCache.put('second.html', '<b>Second</b> template');
```

Of course the templates content could come from a `$http` call:

```
$http.get('third.html', {cache:$templateCache});
```

Here is the plunker those techniques: http://plnkr.co/edit/J6Y2dc?p=preview

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I like the template cache Idea because I do not want to put things into a script tag. How to use it? Documentation is bad. I saw the fiddle in one of the comments there. But I want to load from a url.

Comment: Updated the answer based on the comments

Comment: Can you please repost the plunker, as the one mentioned is not loading

Comment: I sometimes use the inline `<script>` tag together with server-side includes. This lets me keep my partials as separate files for organizational purposes, but still delivers everything in one document.

Comment: Do you know if there's a speed boost in choosing one solution vs another?

Comment: I want to follow the second approach,the confusion is  $templateCache.put('second.html', 'What data should I add here);, I have a tamplet with images and data. like 100 images and 200 data(ex, Price, name, description, descount etc). the tamplet is loaded in ng-view. I am new in angular js.

Comment: I am caching templates using http call, but the the problem is the name of the cached template would be the url forexample: $http.get('app/correction/templates/group-correction-table.html', {cache:$templateCache}); and then whenever I want to load the template I have to use this ugly name :( which I don't like, Like this: <td  ng-include="'app/correction/templates/group-correction-table.html'">

Comment: How do you extract the html from the http.get html file retreived?

Comment: Below code worked for me in JsFiddle.net for custom directive templateUrl $templateCache.put('second.html', '<b>Second</b> template'); Thanks :-)

Answer (score 25):

If you use Grunt to build your project, there is a plugin that will automatically assemble your partials into an Angular module that primes $templateCache.  You can concatenate this module with the rest of your code and load everything from one file on startup.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-html2js

Comment: There's also `grunt-angular-templates` which does the same kind of thing - https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-angular-templates - works a treat

Comment: Does this also work for templates on the index file? I have an ng-view and ng-include in my index file and I'm having trouble getting my application to show up.

Answer (score 16):

Add a build task to concatenate and register your html partials in the Angular `$templateCache`. (*This answer is a more detailed variant of [karlgold's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16125388/88204))*

For **grunt**, use [grunt-angular-templates](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-angular-templates).
For **gulp**, use [gulp-angular-templatecache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-angular-templatecache).

Below are config/code snippets to illustrate.

**gruntfile.js Example:**

```
ngtemplates: {
  app: {                
    src: ['app/partials/**.html', 'app/views/**.html'],
    dest: 'app/scripts/templates.js'
  },
  options: {
    module: 'myModule'
  }
}
```

**gulpfile.js Example:**

```
var templateCache = require('gulp-angular-templatecache');
var paths = ['app/partials/.html', 'app/views/.html'];

gulp.task('createTemplateCache', function () {
return gulp.src(paths)
    .pipe(templateCache('templates.js', { module: 'myModule', root:'app/views'}))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('app/scripts'));
    });
```

**templates.js (this file is autogenerated by the build task)**

```
$templateCache.put('app/views/main.html', "<div class=\"main\">\r"...
```

**index.html**

```
<script src="app/scripts/templates.js"></script>
<div ng-include ng-controller="main as vm" src="'app/views/main.html'"></div>
```

Comment: Hi @james I am using this gulp plugin. All .html load properly but when I try to specify html as part of some dialog box plugin (I am using ng-material) it throws 404. ex -  $mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'entityGridCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'user/partials/entityGrid.html'
            });

Comment: Did you replace my app/views references with your user/partials?

Comment: Thx. I am not changing path of partials, I posted my question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29399453/gulp-templatecache-and-using-html-url-for-dialog-box

Answer (score 11):

If you wrap each template in a script tag, eg:

```
<script id="about.html" type="text/ng-template">
<div>
    <h3>About</h3>
    This is the About page
    Its cool!
</div>
</script>
```

Concatenate all templates into 1 big file. If using Visual Studio 2013, download Web essentials - it adds a right click menu to create an HTML Bundle.

Add the code that this guy wrote to change the angular `$templatecache` service - its only a small piece of code and it works: [Vojta Jina's Gist](https://gist.github.com/vojtajina/3354046)

Its the `$http.get` that should be changed to use your bundle file:

```
allTplPromise = $http.get('templates/templateBundle.min.html').then(
```

Your routes `templateUrl` should look like this:

```
        $routeProvider.when(
            "/about", {
                controller: "",
                templateUrl: "about.html"
            }
        );
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use rails, you can use the asset pipeline to compile and shove all your haml/erb templates into a template module which can be appended to your application.js file. Checkout
http://minhajuddin.com/2013/04/28/angularjs-templates-and-rails-with-eager-loading

Answer (score 0):

I just use `eco` to do the job for me.
`eco` is supported by Sprockets by default. It's a shorthand for Embedded Coffeescript which takes a eco file and compile into a Javascript template file, and the file will be treated like any other js files you have in your assets folder.

All you need to do is to create a template with extension .jst.eco and write some html code in there, and rails will automatically compile and serve the file with the assets pipeline, and the way to access the template is really easy: `JST['path/to/file']({var: value});` where `path/to/file` is based on the logical path, so if you have file in `/assets/javascript/path/file.jst.eco`, you can access the template at `JST['path/file']()`

To make it work with angularjs, you can pass it into the template attribute instead of templateDir, and it will start working magically!

Comment: I'm not sure this answers the question, and changing the programming language is probably overkill.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass $state to your controller and then when the page loads and calls the getter in the controller you call $state.go('index') or whatever partial you want to load.  Done.

Answer (score -1):

Another method is to use HTML5's [Application Cache](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/appcache/beginner/) to download all files once and keep them in the browser's cache.  The above link contains much more information.  The following information is from the article:

Change your `<html>` tag to include a `manifest` attribute:

```
<html manifest="http://www.example.com/example.mf">
```

A manifest file must be served with the mime-type `text/cache-manifest`.

A simple manifest looks something like this:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
index.html
stylesheet.css
images/logo.png
scripts/main.js
http://cdn.example.com/scripts/main.js
```

Once an application is offline it remains cached until one of the following happens:

1. The user clears their browser's data storage for your site.
2. The manifest file is modified. Note: updating a file listed in the
   manifest doesn't mean the browser will re-cache that resource. The
   manifest file itself must be altered.

Comment: unfortunately this feature is deprecated now https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Using_the_application_cache so just a heads up, use this approach at your own risk

Comment: According to the HTML standard, "This feature is in the process of being removed from the Web platform. (This is a long process that takes many years.)"  The suggested replacement, Service Workers, is still an "Experimental technology" as of early 2016.  For now, I am still using the Application Cache because it works well for my applications.