# How is modularity mitigated in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs

I've been playing with the seed app for AngularJS and I noticed that most dependencies (controllers, directive, filters, services) for the app are loaded up front. I was wondering how to modularize an Angular app into smaller bytes, where dependencies aren't loaded unless required.

For example, if I had a large application that had a cart, add/edit shipping address, search results, product details, product lists, etc... A user on a shopping site may never encounter any of these views, but it looks like (from the seed app) that the code for these all views are loaded in at startup.

How is modularity mitigated in AngularJS?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've been playing lately with require modules and angular and I've implemented lazy loading of partials and controllers.

It can be easily done without any modifications to Angular sources (version 1.0.2).

Repository: https://github.com/matys84pl/angularjs-requirejs-lazy-controllers .

There is also an implementation that uses yepnope (https://github.com/cmelion/angular-yepnope) made by Charles Fulnecky.

Comment: your solution is very clean too.

Comment: fwiw, I marked this one the answer because it resolves the problem by pointing to relevant boilerplates. I totally agree with the author on the other post, angular implementations are really small, etc... But this solution provides immediate resolve to the question as intended with two examples. +1 on both btw

Answer (score 21):

This question about modularity is being asked quite often here on SO and the google group. I'm not part of core team but my understanding is the following one:

1. You can easily load partials (HTML/templates fragments) on demand by including them (ngInclude) or referencing them in directives / routes. So at least you don't need to download all the partials up-front (although you might want to do so, see the other question here: [Is there a way to make AngularJS load partials in the beginning and not at when needed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690))
2. When it comes to JavaScript (controller, directives, filters etc. - basically everything that is defined in AngularJs modules) I believe that there is no, as of today, support for on-demand load of modules in AngularJS. This issue closed by the core team is an evidence of this: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1382

Lack of the on-demand load of AngularJS modules might sound like a big limitation, but:

- when it comes to performance one can't be sure till things are measured; so I would suggest simply measuring if this is a real problem for you
- usually code written with AngularJS is really small, I mean, really small. This small code base minified and gzipped might result in a really small artifact to download

Now, since this question is coming back so often I'm sure that the AngularJS team is aware of this. In fact I saw some experimental commits recently ( https://github.com/mhevery/angular.js/commit/1d674d5bfc47d18dc4a14ee0feffe4d1f77ea23b#L0R396 ) suggesting that the support might be in progress (or at least there are some experiments with it).

Comment: I saw by watching the network tab that partials are loaded @runtime. Most weight in the apps I've built revolve around mgmt of view/model, so maybe (as you suggest) size won't matter. +1 for your insights.

Comment: Some folks have messed around with using requirejs to load modules on the fly: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!searchin/angular/requirejs/angular/rs1dj097oHA/_GEqy56peE0J

Comment: There's also nice fork of the angular-js repo here that has requirejs integrated. 
https://github.com/mmrath/angular-seed.git

Comment: I'm looking at Angular in part for a pretty large app I work on, and this is definitely a concern. There are currently upwards of 425 html files, with their own js and css, more coming every day. Most are loaded into iframes either as parts of a 'dashboard', or as lightboxed child dialogs. I very much like what I've learned of Angular so far, but there's no way loading all that up front makes any sense. Our current iframe approach should work for Angular though, with the caveat that managing multiple asynch iframes isn't always pretty. So that's another possible strategy.

Answer (score 0):

All we need is put this code in our application config, as that:

```
  application.config [
    "$provide", "$compileProvider", "$controllerProvider", "$routeProvider"
    , ($provide, $compileProvider, $controllerProvider, $routeProvider) ->

      application.controller = $controllerProvider.register
      application.provider = $provide.provider
      application.service = $provide.service
      application.factory = $provide.factory
      application.constant = $provide.constant
      application.value = $provide.value
      application.directive = -> $compileProvider.directive.apply application, arguments

      _when = $routeProvider.when

      $routeProvider.when = (path, route) ->
        loaded = off
        route.resolve = new Object unless route.resolve
        route.resolve[route.controller] = [
          "$q",
          ($q) ->

            return loaded if loaded

            defer = $q.defer()

            require [
              route.controllerUrl
            ], (requiredController) ->
              defer.resolve()
              loaded = on

            defer.promise
        ]

        _when.call $routeProvider, path, route
```

For use add require our components in modules where we need ( provider, constant, directive etc ). Like that:

```
define [
  "application"
  "services/someService"
], (
  application
) ->

  application.controller "chartController", [
    "$scope", "chart", "someService"
    , ($scope, chart, someService) ->

      $scope.title = chart.data.title

      $scope.message = chart.data.message

  ]
```

someService.coffee file:

```
define [
  "application"
], (
  application
) ->

  application.service "someService", ->

    @name = "Vlad"
```

And add to controllerUrl our path to controller for routing:

```
  application.config [
    "$routeProvider"
    , ($routeProvider) ->

      $routeProvider

        .when "/table",
          templateUrl: "views/table.html"
          controller: "tableController"
          controllerUrl: "controllers/tableController"
          resolve:
            table: ($http) ->
              $http
                type: "GET"
                url: "app/data/table.json"
  ]
```

tableController.coffee file:

```
define [
  "application"
  "services/someService"
], (
  application
) ->

  application.controller "tableController", [
    "$scope", "table"
    , ($scope, table) ->

      $scope.title = table.data.title

      $scope.users = table.data.users

  ]
```

And all components have "lazy" load in place where our need.