# Angular: How to get $routeProvider after app.config

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to access $routeProvider in one of my controller in order to add a route.
How do I do that?

```
function Cont($scope,$routeProvider) {

};
```

This doesn't work for me; I am getting: `Error: Unknown provider: $routeProviderProvider <- $routeProvider`

Comment: This has been previously answered. Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13173667/1620332 .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to defer routes definition in Angular.js?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153121/how-to-defer-routes-definition-in-angular-js)

Comment: The useful answer is indeed [How to defer routes definition in Angular.js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153121/how-to-defer-routes-definition-in-angular-js), but the nice thing about this question is you can get here with a web search for the error message.

Answer (score 6):

$routeProvider and other providers can only be injected to a modules config block. What is it that you want to do with the $routeProvider inside a controller?

Comment: It would be nice to explain *why* providers can only be injected into config blocks (I think this is explained in Module Loading & Dependencies section of the [Module developers' guide](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/module)).

Answer (score 1):

In the controller, $route is accessible but $routeProvider is not. Maybe you can just copy the function out, for example, the 'when' and 'pathRegExp'

See jsfiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5FUQa/1/

```
  function addRoute(path, route) {
     //slightly modified 'when' function in angular-route.js
  }
  addRoute('/dynamic', {
    templateUrl: 'dynamic.tpl.html'
  });
```

Also see: [How to defer routes definition in Angular.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153121/how-to-defer-routes-definition-in-angular-js/)