# Inject routes dynamically in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

I'm using angular to dynamically create another angular app. I was wondering if there is a way to inject routes dynamically. Something like

```
angular.module('app').controller('CreateCtrl', function ($scope,$routeProvider) {
  var count = 0;

  $scope.addPage = function(){  
    $routeProvider.when('/'+count, {
       templateUrl: 'views/created.html',
       controller: 'CreatedCtrl'
     });
    count++;
  };

});
```

I know this code is silly but I hope it transmits what I'm trying to do. When user intercts with the application he/she will create new routes... is that possible?

Comment: This should answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13173667/17815

Comment: Ahhh thank you so much!!! Buu Nguyen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways:

**Option 1**

modifying the routes object directly, as suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/13173667/17815

```
$route.routes['/dynamic'] = {templateUrl: 'dynamic.tpl.html'};
```

Be careful: you need to add both "/newurl" and "/newurl/" (with trailing slash).
see the angular code:

```
this.when = function(path, route) {
routes[path] = extend({reloadOnSearch: true}, route);

// create redirection for trailing slashes
if (path) {
  var redirectPath = (path[path.length-1] == '/')
      ? path.substr(0, path.length-1)
      : path +'/';

  routes[redirectPath] = {redirectTo: path};
}

return this;
};
```

**Option 2**

you can keep a reference to `$routeProvider`:

```
var $routeProviderReference;
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['myApp.controllers']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProviderReference = $routeProvider;
}]);
```

See http://blog.brunoscopelliti.com/how-to-defer-route-definition-in-an-angularjs-web-app

This is polluting the global namespace but you still use the interface to mutate the `routes` object. I guess this makes it easier to maintain.
Maybe you can try to put it in a closure.

In any case, keep in mind that you are expected to do it in a provider to make the application robust. "define before use".