# AngularJS Routing Challenges with one file

Tags: angularjs

I have a large AngularJs application and am struggling with route injection/organization.

Most applications ( from what I've seen ) define all the routes in one big file like https://github.com/IgorMinar/foodme/blob/master/app/js/app.js#L7

My routes are rather complex, for example:

```
app.config(["$routeProvider", function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/navigation/:id', {
        templateUrl: 'app/admin/nav/navigation.tpl.html',
        controller: 'NavigationCtrl',
        title: 'Navigation Config',
        resolve: {
            nav: function($route, NavModel) {
                return NavModel.findOne($route.current.params.id);
            },
            reports: function($route, ReportsModel) {
                return ReportsModel.findAll($route.current.params.id);
            }
        }
    });
}]);
```

since they are complex and pretty coupled to the controller, my route definition page would be HUGE and very confusing.

Is there a better way to declare the routes?  Can you just declare a short version and then extend on it later when that controller is injected?

Comment: you can create several files for routes

Comment: I believe you can have multiple config calls where you inject $routeProvider and continue to add routes to it but I don't think you can modify the $routeProvider after config has been executed http://www.thinkster.io/angularjs/Z9xvxn6klY/angularjs-the-config-function

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can configure `$routeProvider` only in `config` block, since it is a provider. However, you can have multiple `config` sections in your app. That means that if you have several files, each one of them may define another portion of routes inside `config` section of it's own.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">

  <head>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.14/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="another_script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <a href="#/route1">Route 1</a>
    <a href="#/route2">Route 2</a>
    <div ng-view></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**script.js**

```
angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']).
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/route1', {
        template: '<h1>Route 1</h1>'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/route1'
      })
  }]);
```

**another_script.js**

```
angular.module('app').
  config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/route2', {
        template: '<h1>Route 2</h1>'
      })
  }]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZHNTAiW6VsZmQXjSJH2f?p=preview

If you need to add routes dynamically at runtime after application is bootstrapped, you may probably be interested in non-standard solutions like mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153121/how-to-defer-routes-definition-in-angular-js)

Comment: I had them above each controller definition but then the controller had to be fully loaded to do the injection ... I use requirejs and was gonna try to use angularamd but kept hitting this snag

Comment: I wish there was some solution where you could say: $routeProvider.add('/route2') and then it would inject that controller based on a standard structure or one you defined and then add the rest of the resolves, etc when loaded up.