# Capturing the route change in AngularJS when no route matches

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, is there a way to intercept a route change that is not defined in the routeProvider so the route can be looked up in the database and, if a valid match in the database, the new route can be added to the routeProvider?

I've read it is possible to add, dynamically, a route, but I need to do it when the current route has no match.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13153121/how-to-defer-routes-definition-in-angular-js/13173667#13173667

Comment: Thanks, I've read that it is possible to add, but I need to capture the event or the point in the lifecycle of routing that the angular engine did not find a match so I can plug in code to handle the unmatch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would have used the otherwise method of $routeProvider to load a predefined page (controller) to handle undefined routes.

```
otherwise({
    templateUrl: 'addRoute.html',
  });
```

And then, into this controller, get the current route requested using $location ($location.url()).
Add this route dynamically if needed :

```
$route.routes['/new'] = {templateUrl: 'new.html'};
```

Finally, redirect to this route using :

```
$location.path('/new');
```

Obviously, for this to work you will need to inject $route and $location as dependency to your controller.

Comment: This method worked perfectly for me.   I was able to use the $location.path() in the controller associated in the otherwise option like you've mentioned and look up in the database if a new page between the time they downloaded the initial routes to this point.

I did have to use $route.refresh() instead of $location.path('/new').  The current path was already '/new' so the new route didn't load.

Comment: I also want to mention that I added the routes via http://stackoverflow.com/a/22496387/2857047 as the $route.routes['/new'] method above didn't work in v1.3.*

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can do it in controller, you can capture this event as following:

```
$rootScope.$on("$routeChangeSuccess", function (event, next, current) {
    if(!angular.isDefined($route.current.$$route))
      addDynamicRoute('using techniques mentioned above'); 
    else
      handleOtherStuff();
});
```