# AngularJS template. Inner JS not execute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, requirejs

I have many template html page, which include js code. JS do not execute when my RouteProvider loads one of this template.
I do not want to use eval.
I can write my code at outer .js files and use requireJS, but I dont know how I can deactivate my "unused" js file with requireJS.
Can you tell me how can I execute my JS code at my loaded template page?

Comment: adding `JQuery` before `angular` solves this problem.

Answer (score 2):

In the current version (1.0.4 and 1.1.2) AngularJS will *not* execute any JavaScript code contained in a partial specified via `templateUrl` (or `template`).

At the moment your best option is to pre-load most of the code up-front. People were experimenting with requireJS and there are many questions about it on SO and the mailing list. But the truth is that - while loading on-demand can be done for controllers and partials - in general on-demand load is not well supported (see [How is modularity mitigated in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12645720/1418796) for more on this). In practice it might not be a problem since code written with AngularJS tends to be really, really concise so pre-loading things up-front doesn't have adverse performance implications (on the contrary, since all the code is in a browser there are no delays linked to on-demand load).

Load on-demand is a feature that is being worked on as part of AngularJS 2.0.