# AngularJS and adsense

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, adsense

I want to add Google Adsense to my angular app, I found a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17416992/angular-js-adsense).

The problem is that I cannot add the html in my template because I'm loading templates in a script tag (`<script type="text/ng-template"....`) and the `script` tag of adsense breaks the template.

I tried moving the template to the directive:

```
app.directive('Adsense', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    transclude: true,
    replace: true,
    template: '<div><script type="text/javascript" async="async" src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>' +
              '<ins class="adsbygoogle" style="display: inline-block; width: 234px; height: 60px;" ' +
              'data-ad-client="ca-pub-xxxxx" data-ad-slot="xxxxx"></ins>' +
              '<script type="text/javascript">(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});</script></div>',
    link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {}
  }
})
```

But the javascript is not executed when the directive is set up (which seems to be the wanted behavior [AngularJS template. Inner JS not execute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676695/angularjs-template-inner-js-not-execute)). There's another way?

Comment: you ever end up making this work?

Comment: had to move the template to an external html file and load it as an html include or angularjs directive's template

Comment: you have any code you could show please? :) would really really appreciate it

Comment: You could also add your template in the $templateCache in a run() call.

Comment: Or, if you want to create a directive, just append the code to the element in the link function.

Comment: Why even bother with the script tags, the file needs to loaded and the tiny bits of JS need to be run, it doesn't have to be inserted as HTML inside a script tag. Only the <ins> tag is needed on the document.

Comment: Did you try to put the adsense code in the `run()` function of your AngularJS module?

Comment: The template will NOT execute JS. The `link` section is for that. Put your javascript into link section instead of your template.

Answer (score 3):

Googling: https://gist.github.com/endorama/7369006

```
/*global angular */
(function (ng) {
  'use strict';

  var app = ng.module('ngLoadScript', []);

  app.directive('script', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: false,
      link: function(scope, elem, attr) {
        if (attr.type=='text/javascript-lazy') {
          var code = elem.text();
          var f = new Function(code);
          f();
        }
      }
    };
  });

}(angular));
```

Then on your template:

```
<script type="text/javascript-lazy">
  console.log(true);
</script>
```

Use something like this, or modify to load some specifyc file or use https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad

There are so many ways.