# Load Angularjs controllers in ngView

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, web

I'm new to Angular and just started to build a test project to learn it, now have a problem with loading controllers **OnDemand**.
let's code a bit, I have the following HTML:

#### index.html

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="MyApp">
        <a href="/child"> CLICK ME </a>
        <div ng-view></div>
    </div>
    <script>
        angular.module("MyApp",['ngRoute'])
            .config(function($routeProvider) {
                $routeProvider.when('/child', {
                    templateUrl: 'somwhere/child.html',
                    controller: 'childCtrl' <!-- will remove -->
                });
            }) <!-- will remove contoller defination below -->
            .controller('childCtrl', function($scope) {
                $scope.data = DoHeavyCalc();
            });
    </script>
</body>
```

what is obvious to me is that I should define my `controller` **exactly where I config my `module` (MyApp)**, which doing this depends on `DoHeavyCalc()` which is not needed right now! (think this method does a big calculation, but it should be run only when the user clicks on the link, not at the beginning of the app).

Now I want to load the and define the controller inside `child.html` instead of my `index.html`. OK, so I removed the sections marked in above code and tried to write the `child.html` like this:

#### child.html

```
<div ng-controller="childCtrl">
    {{data}}
</div>
<script>
    angular.module("MyApp")
        .controller('childCtrl', function($scope) {
            $scope.data = DoHeavyCalc();
        });
</script>
```

but is causes an error:
`` [ng:areg] `childCtrl` is not a function. got undefined. ``

also i tried to put `script` tag in `child.html` before the `div` tag, but it didn't affect anything.

Now my question is, how can i define and load the `controller` OnDemand and do my heavy work just when the user routes to a certain location not at the beginning of app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are asking about lazy loading ! By default angular doesn't support lazy loading, what you can do ? you can use any third party library like `requirejs` or others.

Currently angularjs doesn't execute any javascript inside `templateUrl` or `template`, [more details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14676695/angularjs-template-inner-js-not-execute)

Here is a working example of [lazy loading](http://plnkr.co/edit/aiarzVpMJchYPjFRrkwn?p=preview) using requirejs.

Also there is some discussion regarding onDemand script loading 
[Lazy loading angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19134023/lazy-loading-angularjs-modules-with-requirejs)

Answer (score 0):

In the child.html page do not include ng-controller attribute. Already child.html is associated with the childCtrl controller. Just remove the attribute ng-controller from the child.html page

Comment: Does it works ? Where OP talking about  onDemand script loading. How `child.html` associated with `childCtrl` where he want to remove that controller definition from routing ?