# Angular.js: script tags in partial page?

Tags: angularjs

We are writing an angular.js+require.js app...

Is it possible to load require.js modules in a lazy manner upon loading of a partial page?

Answer (score 3):

With the current version of AngularJS (1.x) all the modules need to be loaded up-front so it is not possible to load them on demand (this is something that is probably going to change in the next version).

What you can load on-demand today are partials and globally defined controllers. People were experimenting with different approaches for using require.js and AngularJS, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12645720/1418796) has more info.

Having said the above usually code written with AngularJS is extremely concise as compared to other frameworks. As such it can be safely downloaded up-front (some really large applications use this approach). So I would advice against putting require.js up-front.