# Is there a way to group all ng-includes into one http request?

Tags: angularjs, minify, angularjs-ng-include

We usually have multiple `ng-includes` in every main html/jsp pages, I was wondering if there a way to group all `ng-includes` into one http request?

Comment: This is essentially the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690

Comment: Thanks, if you would put that in an answer I would be able to accept it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make angularjs load partials in the beginning and not at when needed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very similar question was answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12346901/1418796

In short, yes, it is very easy to pre-load partials with AngularJS, wither by using the `script` directive (and thus pre-load partials inside the initial HTML download) or putting partials into the `$templateCache` (in this case partials are downloaded with JavaScript).

More details and code examples in the referenced question.