# How do I use Angular JS as a templating engine?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

This **[post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when)**  goes into detail how to bind loading template partials on events.

But what if I wanted to **load template partials on page load** similair to a templating engine like Smarty?

*For example in Smarty:*

```
<html>
<body>
{include file="templates/header.html"}
<span>Dude, this has too be possible in Angular JS...</span>
{include file="templates/footer.html"}
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the ngInclude directive. The documentation and an example can be found here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngInclude

Comment: But does it even make sense?