# ng-repeat + ng-click not working as expected

Tags: angularjs

Seems that this is a very common issue with angular.  The substitutions happen, but the ng-click fails to click (or so it seems to not be called).  Can someone tell me why this fails?

```
<ul>
     <li ng-repeat="color in colors"> 
         <a ng-click="chooseColor({{$index}})">{{color.name}}</a>
     </li>
</ul>
```

here is the fiddle.

It seems to be the {{$index}}.  If i replace that with a static number, it works.

Note: found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539038/ngrepeat-does-not-work-inside-angularui-bootstrap-dialog) - but it was not helpful.

Comment: Quick note in using `$index` for changing a value in the scope. If you filter the original array using `| filter: sth` method (basically if you filter on the view), then the index on the view could be different than the actual, nonfiltered array. It is better to accept the value itself rather than the index.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The `{{}}` bits are used templating (interpolation).  This should work for you:

```
ng-click="chooseColor($index)"
```

The `ng-click` directive is looking for <del>real JavaScript code</del> an [Angular Expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression), not text that it needs to interpolate.

Comment: Note, ng-click requires an [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) (not JavaScript code).