# Angular.js - Prevent Direct Access to Partial Views

Tags: angularjs

I want the users to not be able to view the partials directly when accessing their url in the browser. For example if my partial view is located in:

```
/partials/myPartial.html
```

I can still directly access it and see the odd markup. Is there a way to prevent it and make the partial views only available through angular? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Well, not really.

At the end of a day a browser needs to be able to access a partial to download it. If a browser can do this your users will be able to do so as well. You might eventually make it a bit harder for them to hit partials directly (for example to by configuring your server so it only responds to request with a certain header and configure `$http` to send this header on each XHR request).

The other possibility is to pre-load partials up-front as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12346690/1418796) and not expose them via HTTP at all (actually this is a good practice for production deployments anyway).

Otherwise it is hard to propose a meaningful solution without knowing what is the exact problem (functionally speaking) that you are trying to solve.

Comment: ASP.NET has something called ChildAction which does something like this but maybe because it's a server side language. I kinda hoping angular also has it but I can live without it so thanks anyway.

Answer (score 16):

I put a `<script>` at the top of every view partial that checks if the variable containing the main app Module exists, if not redirect to `index.html`

If in `app.js` the appModule is defined in this way:

```
var appModule = angular.module('myApp',["ngRoute","ngResource"]);`
```

At the top of the partial insert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  if(typeof appModule === 'undefined'){
    document.location.href="index.html";
  }
</script>
```

Comment: 3 years later and this is exactly what I needed. It's so simplistic I feel dirty using it.