# Where do the "list.html" and "detail.html" files live in AngularJS home page "Wire up a Backend" sample?

Tags: angularjs

I am studying AngularJS home page samples and particularly the project/Wire up a Backend one:
http://angularjs.org/#project-html

By opening the jsFiddle "***Edit me***" page, I noticed that the "`list.html`" page is inlined in the main page as follows:

```
 <script type="text/ng-template" id="list.html">
  etc...
```

Is this the best way to proceed or are there other alternatives?

Thanks in advance for your comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you see in the main page is the usage of the `<script>` directive documented here: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:script

By using this directive you can make sure that templates (partials) for your application are loaded up-front and not on demand. This results in fewer HTTP round-trips and - generally speaking - better user experience with less "waiting" time. There are other techniques that you can use to pre-load partials, all of them described in this response: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12346901/1418796

But AngularJS is perfectly capable of downloading partials on the fly so you can remove the `<script>` tags, put partials on your WWW server and have AngularJS download them when needed.

So all depends on the context: during the development time you would sometimes want your partials downloaded on demand for faster turn-arounds. For production deployments you would likely want to pre-load partials as described in the mentioned SO response.