# Is it possible to fetch templates from $templateCache when configuring my $routeProvider?

Tags: configuration, angularjs

My intention is to load all the templates of my web app with one single call to an external JSON file containing a list of all the template names and values.

I am currently loading these templates on the run phase of my app:

```
app.run(function ($http, $templateCache) {
    $http.get('/templates/all.json').success(function (data) {
        var i;
        for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            $templateCache.put(data[i].name, data[i].template);
        }
    });
});
```

However, the Angular.js config phase executes before the run phase, so when I intend to load from the templateCache:

```
app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    //App routing
    $routeProvider.
        //Homepage
        when('/', {templateUrl: 'home.html'}).

        //My schedule
        when('/my-schedule', {templateUrl: 'my-schedule.html'});
});
```

Angular tries to load `home.html` from the server, because the `$templateCache` hasn't been filled yet.

Suppose that `all.json` contains the templates for `home.html` and `my-schedule.html` for the prevous example.

Is it possible to fill `$templateCache` before configuring the app's `$routeProvider`?

Comment: Look at this as it may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when/12346901#12346901

Comment: @Chandermani, although I aleady based my idea on this answer, it doesn't solve what I'm asking, which is how to fill the `$templateCache` *before* configuring my `$routeProvider`.

Comment: My bad i missed that part :(

Comment: did you try in `resolve` callback of `$routeProvider`?

Comment: @charlietfl Yes, I'm playing with `resolve`, but that won't let me rely on the `templateUrl` attribute in the `$routeProvider` config, will it? Instead, I guess I'll have to do the loading of templates manually.

Comment: my thinking was you load the $templatecache in `resolve` , unless it already exists. What you are trying to do is difficult due to asynch. Not sure if config will look for `template` before `resolve` or not. No compiling can start though before `resolve`

Comment: look in source for angular-ui. they create modules for all the templates, then include those modules as dependencies for main module...might be able to do same

Comment: The templates are not loaded until a route becomes active, which can't happen during configuration.  Preloading data into `$templateCache` should just work.  Paths used won't be normalized, so if your route configuration has `templateUrl: "home.html"` then the key used to populate `$templateCache` should be `"home.html"` (not `"/home.html"`).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem and after couple of hours spent on research I realized that I was asking myself the wrong question, since what I wanted to do **wasn't necessarily loading templates using XHR** but just **being sure that they're cached and stored in one file**.

I have grunt task compiling all my JADE templates to HTML and wrapping them in one big angular module which is loaded as a separate JS file called templates.js. **All these things are done automatically in background, so after you've spent 10 minutes configuring it, you can actually forget the monkey work and focus on the code / markup.**

(for the sake of brevity I'm going to skip the JADE part here)

1. edit html file
2. grunt-contrib-watch task:

   1. catches the change
   2. generates angular modules with $templateCache enabled
3. my website is reloaded (using liveReload)

### This is how I approached the problem using Grunt.js / JADE  and html2js:

#### Head section of my index.jade file

```
  script(src='js/modernizr.js')
  script(src='js/vendor.js')
  script(src='js/templates.js')
  script(src='js/app.js')
```

#### Beginning of the main application module (using CoffeeScript here)

```
'use strict'
# Declare app level module which depends on filters, and services
App = angular.module('app', [ 
  'templates' // just include the module and forget it
  'foo'
  'bar']).config(...)
```

#### GruntFile.json (grunt.js config)

I needed to remove ca 80% of the code and left just tasks related to templates, consider it just a draft.

```
module.exports = (grunt)->
  imports = grunt.file.readJSON 'app/imports.json'
  grunt.initConfig
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON 'package.json'



    watch:
      options:
        livereload: yes


      templates:
        files: 'app/**/*.jade'
        tasks: ['buildTemplates']

    jade:
      default:
        options:
          client: no
          wrap: no
          basePath: 'app/'
          pretty: yes
        files:
          'public/': ['app/**/*.jade']

    html2js:
      options:
        module: 'templates'
        base: 'public/'

      main:
        src: 'public/partials/**/*.html'
        dest: 'public/js/templates.js'


    connect:
      server:
        options:
          port: 8081
          base: 'public'
          keepalive: yes


      livereload:
        options:
          port: 8081
          base: 'public'
          # middleware: (connect, options)-> [lrSnippet, folderMount(connect, options.base)]

    copy:
      assets:
        files:[
          src:['**'], dest:'public/', cwd:'assets/', expand: yes
        ]



  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-concat'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-copy'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-coffee'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-clean'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-connect'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-compass'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-watch'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-contrib-livereload'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-jade'
  grunt.loadNpmTasks 'grunt-html2js'

  grunt.registerTask 'buildTemplates', ['clean:templates', 'copy:assets', 'jade', 'html2js:main', 'livereload']


  grunt.registerTask 'default', [ 'connect:livereload', 'watch']
```

#### Result

Single .js file containing list of all application templates wrapped in angular modules similar to this one:

```
angular.module("partials/directives/back-btn.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("partials/directives/back-btn.html",
    "<a ng-href=\"{{href}}\" class=\"page-title-bar__back\"> <i class=\"icon-chevron-left\"> </i></a>");
}]);
```

### Links

1. [grunt.js](http://gruntjs.com/)
2. [grunt html2js plugin](http://gruntjs.com/plugins/html2js)

Answer (score 2):

if you use a HTTP interceptor, you can inject the `$templateCache` there:

```
    $provide.factory('myHttpInterceptor', ['$templateCache', function($templateCache) {
        return {
            request: function(config) {
                // do fancy things with $templateCache here
                return config;
            }
        };
    }]);
```

Comment: Could you make a more complete example? where does that $provide come from ? And how to use that...

Answer (score 2):

[This Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pkozlowski_opensource/qSBHE/2/) is what you need.

Basically - you can just put the `$templateCache` key in the `templateUrl:` property value inside the `$routeProvider` configuration.

Comment: Not really what he's looking for. He'd like to preload the templates before the route provider will use the templateUrl to load the template. I have the same problem, I have templates stored in CouchDB and unfortunately, AngularJS doesn't know how to convert JSON to html templates.