# Using $templateCache in ui-router's template

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Can i use $templateCache in ui-router's template?

The template will be cached in resolve section and i want to use cached template in the same state.

```
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard', {
    url: "/dashboard",
    template: function($templateCache){  
        console.log('test 2');
        return $templateCache.get('templates/template1.html'); // returns undefined
    },
    resolve:{
        baseTemplates: function($ocLazyLoad) {
            // here the template will be cached...
            return $ocLazyLoad.loadTemplateFile(['base/dashboard.html']).then(function(){
                console.log('test 1');
            });
        }
    }
})
// console prints "test 2" before than "test 1"
```

**Update: (+ Code updated)**

I Think resolve section of my code has an issue. because it runs after template section! and it cause returning $templateCache.get being undefined.

I use ocLazyLoad plugin to cache template and it returns a correct promise.

**Why template don't waits for resolve?**

Comment: What error are you getting? Just a guess, but you might have to use `$templateCacheProvider`, since you're defining the routes in the module.config() - [providers](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

Comment: Sorry. It was a mistake. error was from another section. but the main problem is there yet.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The way how to dynamically set the dynamic template is not via the *`template`* property but **`templateProvider`**. There is a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/BMcuXeYuZJVX7rG01pYn?p=preview), and this is the snippet:

```
// this is a run event (executed after config in fact)
// in which we do inejct a value into $templateCache
.run(function($templateCache){ 
    // this could be lazy... elswhere
    $templateCache.put('templates/template1.html'
    , '<div><h4>dashboard</h4></div>');
  })
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

    $stateProvider.state('dashboard', {
      url: '/dashboard', 
      // this is the place where to resolve dynamic template
      templateProvider: function($templateCache){  
        // simplified, expecting that the cache is filled
        // there should be some checking... and async $http loading if not found
        return $templateCache.get('templates/template1.html'); 
      },
    })
});
```

See:

- [Templates](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#templates)

And also, I would say, that not ownly you **can** use the `$templateCache`, but it is already used by `ui-router`. The main service responsible for loading templates *(from url, string...)* for our views is the:

- [$templateFactory](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.util.%24templateFactory)

which, as its code shows, does use `$templateCache` as a natural optimization *(`$templateFactory` [code snippet](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/blob/master/src/templateFactory.js#L82):)*

```
...
/**
* @ngdoc function
* @name ui.router.util.$templateFactory#fromUrl
* @methodOf ui.router.util.$templateFactory
*
* @description
* Loads a template from the a URL via `$http` and `$templateCache`.
*
* @param {string|Function} url url of the template to load, or a function
* that returns a url.
* @param {Object} params Parameters to pass to the url function.
* @return {string|Promise.<string>} The template html as a string, or a promise
* for that string.
*/
this.fromUrl = function (url, params) {
    if (isFunction(url)) url = url(params);
    if (url == null) return null;
    else return $http
        .get(url, { cache: $templateCache })
        .then(function(response) { return response.data; });
};
...
```

Comment: Thanks. using templateProvider and returning result of lazyLoad inside of templateProvider, problem solved. i have not seen templateProvider keyword up to now.

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just [found out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23032361/413785) that you can simply set the key of your `$templateCache` template as the `templateUrl` route property and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if it has already been solved, however, I decided to update my template as follows. I remember that I use AngularAMD / AngularUIRouter, but the templateURL works the same way. I use the function in templateURL, where I pass the "xxx" parameter equal to a new date every time, and this forces the page search again. I hope I have helped okay.

```
.state ('MyReports', {
    parent: 'index',
    url: '/MyReports/:cd_menu',
    views: {
        'BodyView': angularAMD.route ({templateUrl: function (params) {
        return "MyReportsAction/getTemplate?cd_menu="+ params.cd_menu + "&xxx="+ new Date();
    },
    controllerUrl: 'js/app/base/controllers/MyReportsController',
    controller: 'MyReportsController'})
}
})
```

Once this is done, the code below works as expected:

```
$state.go('MyReports', {'cd_menu': cd_menu});
```