# Prevent angular from loading a state template that's already been served

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

Utilising `ui-router` I have the following `state` which is working fine when the visitor has navigated/activated to that `state` from somewhere else within the app e.g. `http://www.example.com` to `http://www.example.com/register`:

```
$stateProvider.state('userRegister', {
    url: '/register',
    templateUrl: 'views/site/user-register.html',
    controller: 'UserRegisterCtrl'
});
```

But when a visitor lands on '`http://www.example.com/register`' from outside the site/app and I've served the page with the '`views/site/user-register.html`' template pre-injected into the HTML, how can I prevent angular from reloading that template? I'm trying to save on http requests you see.

Many thanks

Comment: You can use `$templateCache`. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24658966/using-templatecache-in-ui-routers-template)  answer on how to use it.

Comment: @guranjan-singh Of course, I forgot about the templatecache. So The server could detect the `http://www.example.com/register` page and load the template into a `<script>` tag within the `<body>`. Thanks