# Import controller in HTML file

Tags: html, httpserver

I have a file `controller.js` and I need use in my HTML file but in the moment I make a *GET* request I have 404 not found. 
I have no ideia why this happens. The directory is: 
../resources/js/controller.js
../resources/templates/app.vm

[image]

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="oknok">
<head lang="pt-br">
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>OKNOK Admin</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.1/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../js/controller.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body ng-controller="controller">
<center>
    <h1>Cadastro de veículos</h1>
    <div class="col-xs-4">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="nome"><br>
        <label for="tipo">Tipo:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="tipo"><br>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" ng-model="salvar" ng-click="salvar()">Salvar</button>
    </div>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var oknok = angular.module('oknok', []);

oknok.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http) {
    console.log("1");
    $scope.salvar = function () {
        console.log("entrou");
        $http.post("/veiculos", {
            msg: "teste"
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config){
            console.log("enviado com sucesso");
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config){
          console.log("erro ao enviar");
        });
    };
});
```

Comment: Are you running the app from the local file system, or are you serving it up over a local (or remote) web server?

Comment: your question is nothing todo for AngualrJS so I remove tag and add probably server one

Comment: @Matt Running from local file system

Comment: @DanielaMarquesdeMorais Is the resources folder completely served in your local server? Also, which is the base folder that's served?

Comment: @Alpha Based on her response, I don't think she's using a server

Comment: If that's the case, this could be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124509/why-does-angularjs-ng-view-not-work-locally

Comment: where is you .html file located?

Comment: @timsmiths Is inside app.vm

Comment: @Donal Apache Velocity

Answer (score 0):

Try `<script src="/resources/js/controller.js"></script>`

Answer (score 0):

The HTML file is inserted into the app.vm file (*Apache Velocity*) and it's folder pattern is different. 
You must enter controller.js within the static folder responsible for vm file
../resources/static/js/controller.js
../resources/templates/app.vm