# ng-include not working for Chrome

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created a test.html file to try and debug this issue.

test.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/MainController.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-app="MyApp" ng-controller="MyController">
    <h1>{{ siteHeader }}</h1>
    <div ng-include="'assets/templates/header.html'"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

header.html (inside of assets/templates)

```
<div class="jumbotron">
  <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo.png" />
  <br />
  <h1>{{ siteHeader }}</h1>
</div>
```

When I open index.html in Chrome the first `{{ siteHeader }}` will load the site's title. None of the content of header.html (both siteHeader and the logo PNG) loads beneath it. When I open the same index.html file in Firefox or Safari the header.html content does appear beneath the first `{{ siteHeader }}`.

What am I doing wrong/missing?

Comment: attach the js script in your question, for better analysis

Comment: The only js file that you've included is MainController.js.  Does is it include the definition of MyApp?  Can you post the controller?

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you run the file from your local hard-drive. (`file://`). Chrome block scripts from reading files from `file` origin. This why Angular not success to read the template file and include it to the page.

You have 2 solution:, the simple one is to run chrome in `allow file access` mode. This can help you: [How to launch html using Chrome at "--allow-file-access-from-files" mode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18586921/how-to-launch-html-using-chrome-at-allow-file-access-from-files-mode)

---

The another solution is to create a simple http local server, and run the site from that server. You can run this server using php, nodejs, ruby, python, or anything else. This can helps you: [Run Local Server](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/How-to-run-things-locally#run-local-server)

---

### More Info:

- [Why does AngularJS ng-view not work locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24124509/why-does-angularjs-ng-view-not-work-locally)

Comment: Thank you, this was exactly what I needed.

I am on a Mac and the terminal open /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app --args --allow-file-access-from-files worked great.

Comment: Don't do this! You're opening your machine to attacks. Instead run a local server. 
That flag is dangerous!! Leaves your file system open for access. Documents originating from anywhere, local or web, should not, by default, have any access to local file:/// resources.

Answer (score 1):

Angular won't work when running from a hard drive directly. You should try using [Brackets editor](http://brackets.io). It uses [Live Development](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nhvj1NYC3Uc) and through that you can easily render Angular applications without running an additional server.