# Angular inline template 404 not found in drupal page

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drupal-7, router, angularjs-routing

I'm serving an angular router in a drupal 7 page. The same example works fine in this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/laurencefass/Lsu8p124/.

**HTML**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.home.html">
  <h1> Home </h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="embedded.about.html">
  <h1> About </h1>
</script>

<div ng-app="routerApp"> 
  <div id="navigation">  
  <a href="#/home">Home</a>
  <a href="#/about">About</a>
  </div>
  <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var app=angular.module('routerApp', ['ngRoute']);

app.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {});
app.controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {});
app.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
       templateUrl: "embedded.home.html",
       controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/about', {
       templateUrl: 'embedded.about.html',
       controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

I get the following runtime error:

"Error: [$compile:tpload] Failed to load template: embedded.home1.html   (HTTP status: 404 Not Found)
  http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0-beta.1/$compile/tpload?p0=embedded.home1.html&p1=404&p2=Not%20Found
  minErr/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:68:5
  handleError@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:17751:1
  processQueue@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:14814:11
  scheduleProcessQueue/<@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:14830:27
  $RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:16058:9
$RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:15869:15
$RootScopeProvider/this.$gethttps://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:16166:13
done@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:10607:36
completeRequest@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:10805:7
requestLoaded@https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-beta.1/angular.js?nwma5b:10750:1

Answer (score 0):

The scripts need to be inside the ng-app div for inline scripts to work otherwise angular is looking for a file. not the best implementation, nor obviously documented, but it works for testing purposes. [Using Inline Templates in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124767/using-inline-templates-in-angular)