# Inline template in angular with dynamic url

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-routing

Hi I want to use a similar functionality like :
[Using Inline Templates in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124767/using-inline-templates-in-angular)

But in my case url will be dynamic. for example in below code url will have /first or /second but in my case it will have the category id. there can be 100 of category so I could not write 100 condition

```
  learningApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {$routeProvider.
    when("/cat1",{ controller: "SimpleController", templateUrl: "temp1.html"}).
    when("/cat2", {controller: "SimpleController", templateUrl: "temp2.html"}).
    otherwise({redirectTo : "/first"});
```

});

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="cat1.html">
<div class="view">
    <h2>First View</h2>
    <p>
        Search:<input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    </p>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'name' | filter: filterText "><a href="#">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.school}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="cat2.html">
<div class="view">
    <h2>Second View</h2>
    <p>
       Search:<input type="text" ng-model="filterText" />
    </p>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li ng-repeat="cust in customers | orderBy:'name' | filter:    filterText "><a href= "#">{{cust.name}} - {{cust.school}}</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and definitely I will have a section with id as category id corresponding to each category.

Comment: For example shown you only need one route and one template. Use `$routeParams` in the url for the category ID. Sounds like you need to study some routing tutorials and read the `ngRoute` docs

Answer (score 0):

You can specify Your URL like this:

```
.when("/category/:catId") {
    controller: "ControllerName",
    templateUrl: "templateURL",
}
```

And inside your controller:

```
.controller('ControllerName', ['$scope', '$routeParams', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    var $scope.categoryFromRoute = $routeParams.catId;
}]);
```

E.g. - Navigating to "/category/1" will lead to `$routeParams.catId` having the value equal to 1, inside the controller.