# angularjs / rendering Performance difference between inlining or using ng-include

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-include

I can use ng-include to include a partial inside an angular view or I can use server side partials to do it on the server. I'm thinking about using server side partials instead of angular partials and then ng-include (with the script tag) because I read somewhere that angular partials create new scopes and this can hurt performance on $digest.

Is there any validity to this. What is the effect on performance when using angular includes

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`ng-include` will create a new scope and register a watch (on a path expression used by `ng-include`) on a scope where the `ng-include` is used. While this incurs some additional processing it is still JavaScript-objects based and as such is very fast. The effect of a new watch plus an additional scope should be totally negligible in most cases.

The only real difference I can see is that `ng-include` will include / render your partial asynchronously, so you might see a bit of delay, especially when fetching partials over the network (but this can be mitigated by pre-loading partials as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12346901/1418796)

In short: **in most cases the effect of `ng-include` should be negligible if partials are pre-loaded**.

One last comment: "*premature optimization is the root of all evil*". Don't start micr-performance adjustments until you measure performance of *your* application and determine that `ng-include` is a bottleneck.

Comment: On the other hand, ng-include(s) inside ng-repeat(s) will start very fast to show big performance degradations because of the async mecanism. The best optimization I made in my angularJS app was creating a ng-include-cached directive (synchronous when hitting cache).

Comment: @Guillaume86: Do you care to share the source code for that directive? I'd be very interested.

Comment: @paldepind here it is: https://gist.github.com/guillaume86/9272837 but you will probably want to write a new one with the last ngInclude code from the last angular version. Mine used an old 1.0.x as the base.