# Dual routing in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, url-routing

The AngularJS application uses the ui-router. There are two types of pages:

1. Routes specified explicitly in routes.js
2. Routes derived dynamically on demand

When the page loads the application makes a request for data (type, variables). How to load a template and the controller of the page based on its type?

```
/**
There is an option with this routing, but then it will not work the other routed to specified explicitly
*/
/* routes.js */
// definition of "page" state

/* PageController.js */
// getting type of page
$scope.type = res.data.type;

/* page.jade */
div(ng-if=«page.type == ‘index’»)
    div(ng-controller=‘IndexController’)
div(ng-if=«page.type == ‘catalog’»)
    div(ng-controller=‘IndexController’)
```

It is not clear how to load templates, and there is the question of the performance of this solution. Perhaps there is a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

In your IndexController, put your logic to fetch the page you want to display. Then store this information into the scope.

In you view use [ngIf](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngIf) and [ngInclude](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude) to load your templates depending of you variable value.

Check the example bellow.

*routes.js*

```
angular.module('yourApp', ['ngRoute', ...])
    .config(function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'template0.html',
                controller: 'IndexController'
            });
    });
```

*template0.html*

```
<div ng-if="page.type == 'index'">
  <div ng-include="template1.html"> ... </div>
</div>
<div ng-if="page.type == 'catalog'">
  <div ng-include="template2.html"> ... </div>
</div>
```

In both cases your controller will already be loaded for the template0.html.

Comment: If the partials views are pre-loaded, using ng-include is negligible in term of performance hits. Take a look at this answer: [angularjs / rendering Performance difference between inlining or using ng-include](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16621995/angularjs-rendering-performance-difference-between-inlining-or-using-ng-includ).