# Searching for acceleration

Tags: javascript, http, angularjs

I am using $routeProvider in Angular. Whenever I go to particular route I see log in the console:

```
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8080/root/partials/view1.html".
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:8080/root/partials/view2.html".
...
```

At this point the particular pages are cached I think in the browser and could be referenced faster. How can I make a XHRs for all my routes in the background when the Angular is referenced first time? I search for something like this:

```
for ( /* every page inside routeProvider */ ) {
    // XHRs the page
}
```

Comment: Seems to be duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when/12346901#12346901

Comment: Seems to be similar. In other hand doesn't explain how to add whole bunch of partials (from route) to cache. I would say is more general. Edited a bit.

Answer (score 3):

Your question is answered with examples in the [documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24templateCache).

To summarise: you can inject `$templateCache` into your run method (possibly along with `$route` if you want to get all the template URLs from the route table), and insert templates into the cache.

HTH!

Comment: Going through $route would be nice, but seems this requires additional ngRoute module from angular-route.js

Comment: In the recent versions of AngularJS, true! They've been separating functionality into modules, and I suspect they will do more and more of it!

Answer (score 2):

I use [grunt-angular-templates](https://github.com/ericclemmons/grunt-angular-templates) for that purpose. It's a grunt task which concatenates & pre-load angular templates to `$templateCache`. I run it only in production mode when building project, to avoid increased build time in dev mode.
You can use it as follows (assuming you use grunt):

```
        ...
        ngtemplates: {
            myProject: {
                options: {
                    prepend: '/',
                    concat: 'out\\app.min.js'
                },
                src: ['app/**/*.html'],
                dest: 'out/templates.js'
            }
        }
       ...
```

It concats all html files from app dir to `templates.js` and then append `templates.js` file to `app.min.js` file. In production there is only `app.min.js` file with all js code and templates. Works great for me (and for you it should too, assuming your js code is in reasonable size).

Comment: This is interesting. I am not using grunt, but maybe same day will make a trial.