# Using dynamic layouts from json response: angularJS

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, layout

In my web app, in a search result, each item can have a different look according to the type of item. To achieve this, I was thinking of including the layout with data placeholders for that particular item in the json response. How do I bind the scope data to the placeholders in the json response template?

for eg.
My search result would look something like :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
<div ng-bind-html="item.template"></div>
</li>
```

And the JSON response would look like :

```
[{
"template_name":"One",
"template":"<div ng-repeat='subitem in item.subitems'>{{subitem.name}}</div>",
"subitems":[{name:"John"},{name:"Jane"}]
},
{
"template_name":"Two",
"template":"<div ng-repeat='subitem in item.subitems'>{{subitem.name}}</div>",
"subitems":[{name:"John"},{name:"Jane"}]
}
]
```

Like you can see, I need to bind the placeholders in the json response with the scope data. Is there any way to do it? If not, how do you suggest i should address this situation?

Thank You!

Comment: Add the templates for the types via the template cache, then all your solution needs to know is that type X maps to template Y. Your JSON *data* responses don't need to have part in this.

Comment: My templates need to be dynamically built in the server. That is why I couldnt opt for locally stored templates.

Comment: They need to be built *as you're fetching the data*? That doesn't make any sense. You can dynamically build them all you want, and then add them to the template cache - e.g. see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12346690/is-there-a-way-to-make-angularjs-load-partials-in-the-beginning-and-not-at-when

Comment: Well. yes. I know it sounds absurd. But here's the case. Its a search result page. Each result item could look different according to the type of the result item. So, there is no way of knowing which template to use until i read the individual item. That is why I decided to send the template data with the json response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While this will obviously not work:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div ng-bind-html="item.template"></div>
</li>
```

Since you are telling angular to display html that is inside `item.template` but what you really want is to tell it to treat `item.template` as it would be markup that should be parsed in a similar way to a `template` inside directive.

What you can do however is to define custom directive that will treat `item.template` in a desired manner. For instance:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
  <div dynamic-template="item.template" />
</li>
```

Where `dynamic-template` is defined as follows:

```
 module.directive('dynamicTemplate', function($compile){
    return {
      scope: {
        dynamicTemplate:'='
      },
      replace:true,
      transclude: true,
      link: function($scope, $element, $attrs, _, $transcludeFn){
        // since we have isolate scope - transclude the element so it has access 
        // to item and anything else available inside ng-repeat
        $transcludeFn(function($childElement, $childScope){ 
          var link = $compile($scope.dynamicTemplate);
          var bound = link($childScope);
          $element.append(bound);
        });
      }
    };
  });
```

Of course this is not ideal since changes to `item.template` wont be reflected but you can easily extend this by adding `$watch`.

You can find working example [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/NdQ0euIUuybD1r3rtO5w?p=preview).

Comment: Hi. Thanks so much for the answer. It worked beautifully. However, I dont completely understand how this works. Can you please direct me to an article or something that covers this?