# gulp templatecache and using html URL for Dialog box

Tags: angularjs, gulp, angular-template

Hi I am using the gulp plugin, to create template of all my partials and later merge it with application js script and minified.

```
var partials: ['app/**/*.html', '!app/index.html', '!app/bower_components/**/*.html'],

    gulp.src(partials)           
   .pipe(plugins.angularTemplatecache("templates.js", {module: "mainApp", root: "app/"}));
```

All .html load properly but when I try to specify html as part of some dialog box plugin inside some controller (I am using ng-material) it throws 404. ex -

```
$mdDialog.show({
                controller: 'entityGridCtrl',
                templateUrl: 'user/partials/entityGrid.html'
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your gulp task, the `root:` path must match how your reference the html. So, change `root: "app/"` to  `root: "user/partials"`. *(Or vice-versa)*

Comment: Hi james, my partials are scattered around multiple folders at root level, some are in /partials, /user/partials, /report/partials etc. But these all are inside app/ folder.

Comment: Thanks James. I managed to resolve it now. Yes, the issue was with reference, there were extra "/" as prefix when I was referring to .html from templateUrl, I removed it and it worked. I also removed root: option.

Comment: Similar to Sutikshan's comment, where he figured out his problem by removing the ("/") character; this helpled me solve my problem.  The gulp-angular-templates task was correctly injecting the HTML into the javascript file, but I was getting 404 in the deployed site; it turned out that for the partials, there was an extra slash at the beginning in the templateUrl string.  This was causing the problem.  Weirdly, it worked in dev with or without the slash at the beginning; but it was causing the 404 error in the deployed version.  Removing the slash at the beginning solved it for me.